# Invariant space

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove the following statement: the integration operator $T: P(F) →
P(F),$
$$T(a_nz^n + a_{n−1}z^{n−1} + \cdots + a_0) = a_n{z^{n+1}\over n + 1}+ a_{n−1}{z^n\over n}+ \cdots + a_0z$$
has an invariant one-dimensional space.

Solution:

Here are my scratch ideas: dimension of the polynomial is $n+1$ and $P(F)$ is invariant under T if $z^n$ is element of $P(F)$ implies $Tz^n$ is element of U.

Here is my approach: Polynomial of zero degree has 1 dimension. 
Counter example: take a polynomial from $P(F)$ such that $a_0+a_1z^1$, then integrate term so we have $a_0 z + {a_1\over 2} z^2$ but we lost the constant term after integration. Thus, T does not have an invariant one-dimension space.

Any hints and suggestions are welcome and appreciated !

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $U$?  Is it the hypothetical invariant subspace?

Comment: U is just subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. If $U$ is an invariant subspace of $P(F)$ for the operator $T$ and $f \in U$, then $T(f) = bf$ for some scalar $b \in F$.
2. Every polynomial $f = a_n z^n + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0$ has a leading term.
3. For $f \in U$, what is the leading term of $T(f)$?

---

Suppose that $f = a_n z^n + \cdots + a_1 z + a_0$ generates a one-dimensional subspace $U \subset P(F)$.  In other words, $U = \{ bf \mid b \in F \}$.  (So $f \ne 0$; otherwise $\dim U = 0$).  Further assume that $\deg(f) = n$.  This means that $a_n \ne 0$ and that $a_k = 0$ for all $k > n$.

Now, the leading term of $T(f)$ is $\dfrac{a_n}{n+1} z^{n+1}$, and so $\deg \bigl( T(f) \bigr) = n+1$, showing that $T(f) \notin U$.

What have we shown?  $T(U) \nsubseteq U$ or that $U$ is not invariant.  Since $U$ was an *arbitrary* one-dimensional subspace of $P(F)$, this shows that a one-dimensional subspace is not possible.

---

A slight variation on this argument actually shows that any finite-dimensional subspace cannot be invariant under $T$.  (Consider the degree of $T(f)$, where $f$ is a polynomial of maximal degree in the proposed finite-dimensional subspace.)

Comment: Thanks! am I on right track?

Comment: You are kind of on the right track, but you're mixing up your quantifiers.  A counterexample is enough to disprove a statement about *all* something.  But to prove nonexistence you have to consider an arbitrary subspace (*any*) and show that it leads to something that is not allowed.

Comment: I can edit the answer to say more if you like.

Comment: You are more than welcome to do that. leading term of $T(F)$ is ${a_n}z^n$ and what does it have to do with that? Yeah, counter example is more preferable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  On this and on other questions that you've asked on this site, if you find an answer to be helpful, you can select it.  This way the question is marked as answered.